# Is combining an Alpha1AdrenergicReceptorAgonist (A1ARA) nasal spray with a steroid nasal spray a plausible practice?

Tags: steroids, nasal-congestion, adrenaline

[I didn't find such a combo spray on AAAAI's website](https://www.aaaai.org/tools-for-the-public/drug-guide/nasal-sprays).

[According to drugs.com](https://www.drugs.com/drug-interactions/prednisone-with-sudafed-pe-congestion-1936-0-1853-16109.html) no interactions been found between Prednisione (an oral corticosteroid) and Sudafed PE Congestion (containing phenylephrine) nasal preparation; as this datum is about oral corticosteroid and and oral phenylephrine I assume that if this is correct than combining a nasal phenylephrine with a nasal steroid shouldn't be a problem, but I will try to further consolidate this thought.

[It's possible to combine both an antihistamine (such as azelastine) and a steroid in a spray](https://www.mayoclinic.org/drugs-supplements/azelastine-and-fluticasone-nasal-route/description/drg-20075580).
Why than should A1ARAs be different than antihistamines in that regard?

It may be extracted from [this study](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/30054985/) that such a combination is possible, yet it wasn't effective for chronic rhinitis.

Is combining an Alpha1AdrenergicReceptorAgonist (A1ARA) nasal spray with a steroid nasal spray a plausible practice?

Comment: You posted a link showing that it was found plausible but ineffective, so why are you asking if it's plausible?

Comment: I think you had a mistake there - possible, not plausible.

Comment: The main question is *why* you want an alpha agonist and a corticosteroid in the same spray, given they tend to have much different dosing regimens. When they combine, say, analgesics, it's because you often can use a single pill instead of one caffeine and one acetaminophen pill.

Comment: Combining may be good in case of vasomotor rhinitis and medicamentosa rhinitis **simultaneously**.

Comment: Except rebound congestion is *caused* by phenylephrine in the first place. You shouldn't use nasal decongestants for long periods for this very reason. I feel like this is a chameleon question here, and you're really looking for an answer to another question. If so, you should just ask that instead of beating around the bush (assuming it's not soliciting medical advice).